# What happen if I try to publish a facebook action on a user who doesn't have Timeline yet?

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, facebook-timeline

As a Facebook app that publishes facebook open graph actions instead of old post wall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the app requires the user to have the Timeline (publish open graph action), the user will switch to timeline automatically.